# fill transparent png on canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas

I have the following question for filling up a transparent “png” image on a canvas. Filling up a circle/rectangle works like a charm. When I replace the circle or rectangle by a png, then it doesn’t fill as I want.  Here’s the code.
When I replace the line "context.arc...."  by the line "context.drawimage....." the png is shown on the canvas , but the fill doesn't work.

```
  <script>
     var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
     var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
     var ThumbImg = document.createElement('image');
     var MyShape = document.createElement('image');
     ThumbImg.src = 'stof2.jpg';
     MyShape.src = 'Myshape.png';

     //-----begin custom shape-----

    context.arc(100,100, 100, 0, Math.PI*2,true);
    //context.drawImage(MyShape, 100, 0, 300,300);   

    //-----End custom shape-----

    //---Start Fill custom Image------
    context.fillStyle = context.createPattern(ThumbImg ,'no-repeat') 
    context.fill();     
    //---End Fill custom Image------

</script>
```

Comment: [`drawImage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/drawImage) method is not part of the Path drawing commands. [`fill`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/fill), [`stroke`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/stroke) and [`clip`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/clip) methods only act on pathes. You may want to read some tutorials about canvas, then you may find that there is a solution to do what you want ;-)